# Getting an error on entering special characters using Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, server

I am entering special character into SQL Server using Entity Framework and am getting an error on the server.

Single database two servers, the first one is Localhost and the second one is hosting server.

On localhost this code is working properly.

Error:

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException:' Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
>       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>       at Admin_AddNews.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\newstimenation.in\newstimenation.com\Admin\AddNews.aspx.cs:line 148

Comment: are there 2 databases, or just 2 web servers...do the encoding on the two databases match...do the data types on the columns exactly match

Comment: single database @Ctznkane525

Comment: you need to provide the source code and error

Comment: 'Getting an Error' is a terrible problem description

Comment: 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Admin_AddNews.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\.........\................\Admin\AddNews.aspx.cs:line 148' @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this exception for exception details.
You can find the reason in the error detail.

```cs
try
{
    //_unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var failure in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} failed validation\n", failure.Entry.Entity.GetType());
        foreach (var error in failure.ValidationErrors)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("- {0} : {1}", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MaxLength on the string field was probably exceeded.